# How to add more functionality to this slideshow (images moving from right to left instead of fading?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am implementing a piece of code regarding a slideshow, on which images fade every three seconds allowing the next one to show:

```
<style>
#slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>

<ul id="slides">
    <li class="slide showing">
    <img src="" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
    <img src="" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
    <img src="" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
    <img src="" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    </li>
    <li class="" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000);

function nextSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
</script>
```

Still, i am struggling with trying to implement an animation that allows the images to move from right to left every three seconds (like sliding) instead of fading.

Does anyone know any way to implement that?

Comment: I don't see any animation code in this - where is the code you are trying to use to animate from right to left?

Comment: @Eduardo: Use one of the countless available plugins..

Comment: @1stthomas Could you share a link that is related to what i am looking for?

Comment: @Eduardo: e.g. https://bxslider.com/ - there are options to make it sliding from e to w or v.v.